# SII Suministro Inmediato de informacion del IVA InaccessibleWSDLException

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse, aeat-sii

Buenos dias,

estoy intentando consumir el webservice de pruebas que tiene la aeat para el SII y me aparece el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.
>
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>
> at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Unknown Source)
>     at https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService.(SiiService.java:42)
>     at app.EnvioFacturas.main(EnvioFacturas.java:12)

He generado las clases con

```
wsimport -b bindings.xml -d srcb -keep htt
p://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tri
butaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministr
os/V_07/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl
```

y el contenido del bindings.xml es el siguiente;

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

y el error aparece al intentar instanciar el service:

```
https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService service = new https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService();
https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiSOAP port = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
```

No se si se trata de algun error en la generacion de las clases o en la instanciacion que la estoy haciendo mal. El codigo es el autogenerado con el wsimport y lo unico que he hecho yo ha sido intentar instanciar el service y el port.

¿Alguien puede echarme una mano? 
¿Faltaria añadir algo en la generacion de las clases o en la instanciacion del service y del port?

Comment: No parece un poblema de generación, dado que parece que hay fallos de conexión. ¿Tienes configurados los certificados de la AEAT? ¿Tienes algún firewall que pueda estar parando tu tráfico HTTPS? Porque aunque el WSDL original parece que lo obtienes por HTTP, incluye otros WSDL que están en HTTPS.

Comment: Tengo los certificados de AEAT y a las direcciones https puedo acceder desde el navegador sin problemas. A la pagina de pruebas de la AEAT tambien puedo acceder.

Comment: Corregido. Es un problema del proxy de mi empresa, en una red sin proxy me realiza bien la instanciacion. Gracias.